How to link Service Principal preferredTokenSigningKeyThumbprint to a certificate in keyCredentials
I am trying to get Service Principal and SAML information with Graph, but the preferredTokenSigningKeyThumbprint and the ThumbPrint from keyCredentials.CustomKeyIdentifier don't match
I use this function:
Function Get-MgEnterpriseAppSamlInfo {
    try {
        $servicePrincipalsList = Get-MgServicePrincipal -Filter "preferredSingleSignOnMode eq 'saml'"
        $servicePrincipals = @()

        foreach ($ServicePrincipal in $servicePrincipalsList) {
            foreach ($Cert in $ServicePrincipal.keyCredentials) {
                $servicePrincipals += [PSCustomObject]@{
                    DisplayName                        = $ServicePrincipal.DisplayName
                    KeyType                            = 'SAML {0} Certificate' -f $cert.usage
                    ExpirationDate                     = $Cert.endDateTime
                    DaysUntilExpiration                = (($Cert.EndDateTime) - (Get-Date) | Select-Object -ExpandProperty TotalDays) -as [int]
                    preferredTokenSigningKeyThumbprint = $ServicePrincipal.preferredTokenSigningKeyThumbprint
                    ThumbPrint                         = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($Cert.CustomKeyIdentifier)
                    Description                        = $Cert.DisplayName
                }
            }
        }

        Write-Output $servicePrincipals | Sort-Object DaysUntilExpiration
    } catch {
        Write-Error $_.Exception.Message
    }
}

And the result is like this
DisplayName                        : SAML-TEST
KeyType                            : SAML Sign Certificate
ExpirationDate                     : 14-11-2027 16:31:43
DaysUntilExpiration                : 1095
preferredTokenSigningKeyThumbprint : 7011B644F509062DE8843220C35CC39B1D45A6FF
ThumbPrint                         : fkXXOdNB9V2MNZ/g7F7vgIb70XbwjIEoMFH9cEZSXps=
Description                        : CN=Microsoft Azure Federated SSO Certificate

DisplayName                        : SAML-TEST
KeyType                            : SAML Verify Certificate
ExpirationDate                     : 14-11-2027 16:31:43
DaysUntilExpiration                : 1095
preferredTokenSigningKeyThumbprint : 7011B644F509062DE8843220C35CC39B1D45A6FF
ThumbPrint                         : fkXXOdNB9V2MNZ/g7F7vgIb70XbwjIEoMFH9cEZSXps=
Description                        : CN=Microsoft Azure Federated SSO Certificate


Are you getting any error with the above code ?

No errors with the code

What is the exact issue facing here? @Claus-OleOlsen


I am trying to get Service Principal and SAML information with Graph, but the preferredTokenSigningKeyThumbprint and the ThumbPrint from keyCredentials.CustomKeyIdentifier don't match:

The mismatch occurs when both the key values are representing the same key but in different formats. In order to avoid this conflict, you can conversion technique to convert it to base 64 decode format first.
Note:
Formats:
preferredTokenSigningKeyThumbprint is the HEX representation of the SHA-1 certificate thumbprint and CustomKeyIdentifieris the Base64-encoded representation of it.
Below is the function code to use for format conversion:
Function Convert-Base64ToHex {
    param ([string]$b64ThumbPrint)
    $bytesinfo = [Convert]::FromBase64String($b64ThumbPrint)
    $Bytes = $bytesinfo
    $hex = ($Bytes | ForEach-Object { $_.ToString("X2") }) -join ""
    return $hex
} #provide a valid thumbprint value as input
$Hexvalue = Convert-Base64ToHex -Base64ThumbPrint $b64ThumbPrint


After the above conversion, both values have to match and provide the expected results.
Reference for conversions using PowerShell is detailed in this blog well.

Is the above approach worked for you! @Claus-OleOlsen

The $Cert.CustomKeyIdentifier is returned as System.Byte[], so I tried
ThumbPrint = ($Cert.CustomKeyIdentifier | ForEach-Object { $_.ToString("X2") } ) -join ""
But hist give me a result like this
preferredTokenSigningKeyThumbprint : 7011B644F509062DE8843220C35CC39B1D45A6FF
ThumbPrint                         : 7E45D739D341F55D8C359FE0EC5EEF8086FBD176F08C81283051FD7046525E9B
